# C# WPF - Creating Custom Control. Not sure how to align Text Correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, alignment

I'm trying to create a custom control; similar, say to a Compass, so it is circular.  I have a compass face image, and an arrow image that I can rotate to point the right direction.  The problem is that I have N,S,E,W markers that I want to update at times and thus made them labels.  I divided the field up into percentages and put the labels in the right grid locations.

This all looks great.

BUT when I use this custom control on various pages, some work and some don't.  What it comes down to is the size of the cell of the grid on the new page.  In one case the grid width is 4x the grid height.  The background image grows to fill the height; this is right.  The West and East TextBlocks are way off of the Compass_Face image because the 1/4th the width of the cell is way to the left.  I thought that they would be constrained to the size of the custom control but that appears to not be the problem.

I'm sure that there has to be a way to keep the text constrained to the compass_face image.  Thoughts?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image x:Name="imageBackground" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Source="Resources/compass_face.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="imageArrow" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Source="Resources/arrow.png"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="labelNorth" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="N"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="labelSouth" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="S"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="labelEast" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="E"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="labelWest" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="W"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @CylonGlitch, Could you perhaps provide a screenshot of the issue? I'm having trouble picturing it.

Comment: Ok, sorry it took so long : [Custom Control Layout](https://i.imgur.com/0E1cTvp.png)  When I went and put it on a wide form [My test form](https://i.imgur.com/GZTbZ7F.png)

Answer (score 0):

Grid isn't really the best layout to use in this case, but you can force it to be square by putting a Viewbox around it and assigning your parent grid to a specific size. That will keep your text aligned properly:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid Width="200" Height="200">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--<Image x:Name="imageBackground" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Source="Resources/compass_face.png"/>
        <Image x:Name="imageArrow" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Source="Resources/arrow.png"/>-->
        <Ellipse Fill="CornflowerBlue" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="&#x2191;" FontSize="200" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        <TextBlock x:Name="labelNorth" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="N"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="labelSouth" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="S"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="labelEast" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="E"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="labelWest" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="W"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like what I'm trying to do.. thanks.  I'm testing it now.  :D

Comment: I have tested it and it does seem to fix my problem.  Causes a few other things, such as the fonts are different, but that's fine, I think that is how it should be anyway.  :D  I appreciate your help.

Comment: The only issue I see now is that when I put everything in the ViewBox, the rows have different heights, they seem completely random and don't seem to change.  Almost like everything is set to auto.

Comment: I'd have to see your exact usage. Can you not just get rid of the rows altogether and align your text to `Top` for N, `Right` for E etc with a margin?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  There are a few other things I have to do, such as a button that pops up information about the compass, which is aligned with multiple rows of text at the bottom of the compass (south).  Getting closer to what I want.   Just find it odd that the rows and columns of a grid aren't following the same rules as they did when outside of the ViewBox.